# Vim's ":make" creates a new file

Tags: vim, makefile

I use `:make` in Vim to execute a makefile. The makefile has this output:

```
some errors ...
...
Tiempos
tiempo: updateSW 0:00:00.000311 0.00956216947485
tiempo: total 0:00:00.032524 1.0
```

but after the make process I get this

```
Press ENTER or type command to continue
"tiempo: updateSW 0" [New File]
(16 of 18): 00.000301 0.00922831652206
```

and Vim creates a new file called "tiempo: updateSW 0". Why? , why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second-last line looks like an error message in the file:line:error format, so vim tries to open the file part ("tiempo: updateSW 0"), jump to the error line ("00") and display the message ("00.000311 0.00956216947485"). You have to change the `errorformat` regular expression to avoid this false positive.